# False Positive on Gated Check-Ins

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, tfvc, gated-checkin

I am doing builds using a custom MSBuild Script in TFS2010 SP1.  The Build Type is a gated Check-In and fails even though the MSBuild log shows as successful on my builds.  What would trigger a failure after MSBuild is complete and before The build definition finishes the gated checkin

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the DataCollectors were failing as the test runs were happening.  This was diagnosed in the event log under VSTT.  Unfortunately it doesn't update the normal MSBuild logs and no other information is given into the Workflow logs.

I ended up disabling the datacollections in the local.testsettings file that is being used as part of the build process.